# Sequence contains no elements in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get lowest and highest values in key of a dictionary below

```
public static Dictionary<SimulationResult, List<Student>> SimulationOutput { get; set; } = new Dictionary<SimulationResult, List<Student>>();
```

this is the class in the key

```
internal class SimulationResult
{
    public int Unsolved { get; set; }
    public int ValuePreferences { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting the error in the Sequence contains no elements on the lines below

```
int bestResult = SimulationOutput.Keys.Where(x=> x != null).Select(x => x.ValuePreferences).Max();
```

also on these lines

```
int bestResult = SimulationOutput.Keys.Select(x => x.ValuePreferences).Max();
int LowestUnsonved = SimulationOutput.Keys.Select(x => x.Unsolved).Min();
```

The dictionary is filled in a Parallel for loop.

```
Parallel.For(1, verwerken.Gegevens.AantalIteraties + 1, i =>
{
    PracticumCollectie practicumCollectie = verwerken.Data.PracticumCollectie.Copy();
    StudentCollectie studentCollectie = verwerken.Data.StudentCollectie.Copy();
    studentCollectie.OrderStudentByPreference();
    studentCollectie.AssiningStudentToPracticum(practicumCollectie);

    practicumCollectie.Oplossing.Index = i;
    practicumCollectie.ZetAantalOnopgeloste(studentCollectie);
    practicumCollectie.ZetWaardeVoorkeuren(studentCollectie);

    bool schrijfOplossing = verwerken.Keuze.IsSimuleren ? verwerken.VoldoetAanOndergrenzen(practicumCollectie.Oplossing) : true;

    if (schrijfOplossing)
    {
        SimulationOutput.Add(verwerken.GetBestandsnaam(practicumCollectie.Oplossing), new List<Student>(studentCollectie.Items));
    }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if the code to create the sequence was available.

Comment: It is [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-max(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-int32)))) If there are no elements - how to calculate `Max` ?

Comment: Using a Dictionary could be a problem as it is not thread safe. Maybe a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-6.0) should be used instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use ConcurrentDictionary if you are working with Parallel.

normal dictionaries aren't threadsafe.